# Uninstall Plone/Zope

Tags: uninstallation, plone

I am testing different CMSs, and installed Plone 4 in my server. It is not my chosen one, and I now can´t find a way to uninstall it. I would like a full uninstall.

Regards: Miguel

Comment: Could you please precise how you have installed it and on which OS? Using the unified installer? Using your distribution package manager (apt-get install, yum install, etc.)?

Comment: You know how you installed it (we don't).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you used the Unified Installer, you simply delete the directory and you are done. Plone does not install anything outside of that.

If you used another method to install Plone, you'll need to give more details than that, including the OS you installed it on.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I used the Unified Installer. I was afraid of something outside of its directory. So it seems easy.

Comment: I've tried to do this about 5 times now and pieces of Plone stick around on Ubuntu Server.  I want a fresh install, but Plone keeps pulling in data from the old installation.  I don't have a Zope Instance running at all, I stop plonectl  so I have no idea.  I'm about to abandon Plone as I can't get it to work.  Can't upload files or anything.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record - if you installed Plone on Windows with the official Plone Installer for Windows (ie, downloaded from plone.org), you should use the "Add/Remove Programs" entry for Plone. Simply deleting the Plone folder won't remove the Start Menu shortcuts or the Windows Service for the Zope Server.

Answer (score 1):

If you've done a ZEO install, you may want to remove the group 'plone_group', and the users 'plone_buildout', and 'plone_daemon'.  Just some more advice for cleaning Plone off your system...